# React - which function is closest to the solution - i want duplicate components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to do something like this to start the function of creating a new component after clicking on the button. Moreover I want the div element with its content to appear every time I click a button. (in my case my own component)

For example when i want to create questionnaire and add questions i need a button who let me add input for this question. You know, duplicate components.

I created 3 functions, but I don't know which one is closest to the solution. Can you help me :c ? 3 days i trying  do this. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
const Adding = () => {
    const components = {
        button : Button
    }

      components.map((question, index) => (   
        <Button key={index}/>
      ))
}

//customElementsRegistry.define('input-text', Button , { extends: 'div' });

const AddQ = () => {
    let counter = 0;
const newEl = document.createElement("input-text"); // ta funkcja tworzy tyle komponentów ile chce ale tylko np divy
newEl.innerText = `przykładowy tekst ${++counter}`;
const div = document.querySelector("#ankieta"); 
div.appendChild(newEl);
}

function AddQuestion(){
const el = React.createElement("Button", {}, 'My First React Code');  // ta funkcja renderuje mi tylko jeden w tym wypadku button 

    ReactDOM.render(
        el,
        document.getElementById('ankieta'))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using React, whenever possible, avoid using original DOM functions. Instead, use React's internal mechanisms to generate and modify the DOM:

```js
// React functional component
const App = () => {
  // Maintain a clicked state using `useState`
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  // On click, increment counter
  const onClick = () => setCounter(counter + 1);

  // Generate the array of texts
  // Use `useEffect` to only recalculate when `counter` changes
  const inputTexts = React.useEffect( () => 
    (new Array(counter))
      .map( (_, index) => `przykładowy tekst ${index}` ),
    [counter]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={ onClick }>

      {/* The DIV where you append the generated inputs */}
      <div id="ankieta">
        {
          // Generate the inputs from the texts generated earlier
          inputTexts
            .map( (value, index) => <input key={index} value={value} />)
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Note:** The generated `input`s are not being updated and has a fixed value. This means that their value cannot be modified. If you need to be able to modify them, you'll need to create the corresponding `onChange` function and save the value to some state: instead of using `const inputTexts = useEffect(...)` you'll need to do some more sophisticated state management, or manage it using a self-managed sub-component.